# Latexmk: -interaction=nonstopmode

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I'm trying to use `-interaction=nonstopmode` in the Latexmk configuration file. But I can not. Here's the file:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $_[0]";
```

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong format for the string to specify.  See the [latexmk documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf) for the variable `$pdflatex` for an example.  Modifying that example for your case  gives

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
```

Here, `%O` is a placeholder where latexmk will substitute any other options that latexmk needs to pass to pdflatex, and `%S` is a placeholder where latexmk will substitute the name of the tex file.